# Hibernate Caching Problem

Tags: hibernate, caching, memory, grails, spring-security

I have been dealing with memory issues in my application and believe that I have finally nailed it down by profiling with Yourkit - I cache the User in the session, but each `User` that gets cached is 2MB, which creates a whole lot of memory as users log in and their sessions are saved:

[Users are taking up 50% of RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHoL6.jpg)

[Each User Object is 2MB, some taking 8MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGrU6.jpg)

When I expand each class, it looks like all of the memory is being taking up by the association to `authorities`, which defines the user's roles: [Expanded Class In Yourkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhyM.jpg)

Here is the Hibernate XML for the relevant classes:

User:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.pps.domain" default-lazy="false">

    <class name="User" table="pps_users">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <comment>User</comment>

        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native">
            </generator>
        </id>
 <set name="authorities" inverse="true" table="pps_user_roles" lazy="true">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <comment>User - Roles Associations</comment>
            <key column="user_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="role_id" class="com.pps.domain.Role"/>
        </set>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Role:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.pps.domain" default-lazy="false">

    <class name="Role" table="pps_roles" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <comment>Role</comment>

        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native">
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="description"/>
        <property name="authority"/>

        <set name="users" table="pps_user_roles" lazy="false">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>            
            <comment>User - Roles Associations</comment>
            <key column="role_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="user_id" class="com.pps.domain.User"/>
        </set>
    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

I figured that since the Roles table was caching the Users (and there are over 10,000 users in the system) that the bloated `User` class was a result of this, but removing the `<cache usage="read-write"/>` didn't help. I don't know too much about Hibernate, so I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions?

Note: The project is in Grails 1.3.7 and I am using the (deprecated) `acegi` plugin, if that helps.

EDIT:

I removed both references to `cache` in the `authorities` set as well as in the `Role`. The object actually got bigger. Also, in YourKit, the Object Count for each User is 10,900, which is within a few of the actual users in the system, so it still must be caching them somehow. I need this not to be true!

Comment: What happens if you just remove all of the caching from both classes, just to see how your memory is affected?

Comment: @Mac - Somehow the memory jumps to 10MB per instance loaded, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning off caching, configure your cache to allow fewer objects and to not cache them forever, which it sound like it might be doing. See ["The Second Level Cache"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache) for details on how Hibernate uses the cache and how cache regions are named, so you know how to change the right cache settings.

**Edit:** On second thought, based on your comments, Hibernate caching isn't your issue. What you're describing isn't how caching works in Hibernate. The fact that a Role is cached doesn't mean that all the Users are cached, too. Each type of object is cached independently. You need to look somewhere besides Hibernate's second level caching. The mere fact that loading a Role causes 10k users to load is probably the problem. You don't want that. You might want to take a look at ["extra-lazy" collection fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching). Also check in Yourkit to see exactly what is holding references to these things, if anything.

Comment: It looks like my `Role` class is still caching all Users with that role, which I don't want it to do at all. All users are basically the "Normal" Role, so this results in a Role that has 10,000 User objects connected to it. I figured if I removed the cache line for this that it would not cache at all, but I am not seeing that happening. Do you have any ideas?